# What is the equivalent of using StringContent (System.Net.Http) to make a post request in Python

Tags: c#, python, http, python-requests

I have some C# code that does the following post request:

```
string postData = newFormUrlEncodedContent(params).ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
var postContent = new StringContent(postData, UTF8Encoding.UTF8, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

var responseMessage = httpClient.PostAsync(url, postContent).Result;
```

I would like to do the equivalent in Python using the [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) library. This is what I have:

```
headers = {'content-type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
postContent = requests.post(url, params=params, headers=headers, cookies=previousResponse.cookies)
```

But `postContent.status_code` for the Python code is 404, whereas the C# request returns 200. It's possible that there's something wrong with the params since I retrieve those via some Regex matching from a previous request, but that seems to be working.

**Edit**: I think setting the params parameter is for get requests, not post requests. Also I believe `Requests` [takes care of form encoding](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/):

> Typically, you want to send some form-encoded data — much like an HTML form. To do this, simply pass a dictionary to the data argument. Your dictionary of data will automatically be form-encoded when the request is made

So now I have:

```
postContent = requests.post(url, data = params, cookies = previousResponse.cookies)
```

Now `postContent.status_code == 500`. The stack trace says the data is invalid at the root level. I will look into it.